# How to get the path to the overriden template in Joomla 1.7?

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding

If Joomla or some component have already reset the current template using [`JFactory::getApplication("site")->setTemplate($newTemplateReference)`](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/joomla/includes/JSite.class.html#det_methods_setTemplate) and I don't have an access to the reference of the overridden (previous) template and don't want to make changes in that part of code which resets the template (i.e. saving the old template reference before resetting the template using 'getTemplate()'). Is it possible to get at least the directory name (path) of the overridden template?

I want to use that path in the `index.php` of the new template so I can access some files of the overriden template without beeing dependent on that template name (writing the overriden template path eplictly).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have trouble to understand your exact problem. You want to know where themes override component and module templates?

Comment: I think I understand your question, but I cant find any reference to JSiteInstance anywhere. Is that class part of a component?

Comment: I have modified the question, it was a bit misleading. JSiteInstance was vaguely meant as a instance returned from JFactory::getApplication("site")

Answer (score 0):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$templateDir = JURI::base() . 'templates/' . $app->getTemplate();
```

Comment: In index.php of the new template, this would give me the current template. What I was looking for was a reference to the previous (overriden) template.